# Display all variants from a collection

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to make a list of all available variants for a specific collection. For example I have a collection computer mouse, I want to display all the available variants products of that collection have.

When I add this

```
{% for product in collections.computer-mouse.products %}
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
  <li>{{variant.option1}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It shows list of available variants, but it not displaying all, is there any reason it's not working properly?

Comment: Maybe you want {{ variant.title }} instead of {{variant.option1}}

Comment: It's not that, it displays correct variant name but just not displaying all, it displays variant of first 50 products, can you tell me is there any way I can loop through all products in a collection?

Answer (score 1):

See the Shopify docs for [`collection.products`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/collection#collection-products):

> Returns all of the products inside a collection. Note that there is a **limit of 50 products** that can be shown per page. Use the pagination tag to control how many products are shown per page.

You could try something like this:

```html
{% paginate collection.products by 1000 %}
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    <li>{{product.title}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

But it's not an ideal solution... There's been plenty of discussion about it on the Shopify forums. E.g. [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/liquid-loop-stops-at-50-even-though-there-are-114-items-in-the-collection-any-ideas-37907), [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/vendor-lists-and-pagination-41110) and [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/select-list-for-all-vendors-only-showing-5-many-more-43593).

Comment: is there any way to loop through it, like for first 1000 products and then another 1000, I am trying to store everything in a json object, using this I can get 1000. Thanks for your help.